# Angular, jsPDF Autotable and multiple tables

Tags: angular, jspdf

Anyone can help? I need to create multiple tables in a PDF. I need to set one of the tables not to wrap columns and expand its contents using all the width of the page before break line because it has short columns. I am using Autotable and i tried options like horizontalPageBreak and pageBreak but the table always draw vertically and do breakpage.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks.

This is some help of what I want to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjNwu.png

Comment: share a demo code on what you have on https://stackblitz.com/. Also, elaborate with some image on what is expected so that English won't be a barrier

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Post edited with a link to an example of what I am trying to do. Thanks!!